# Sensor file from gcs to bigquery. If success load it to GCS bucket, else load it to another bucket

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I want to build a Dag like this
[image]

Description:

- I have a file named population_YYYYMMDD.csv in local. Then, I load it to GCS bucket - folder A using GCSObjectExistenceSensor => Done
- Then, I transform it using DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator. Transform sth like column name, data type,...
  Base on whether the population_YYYYMMDD file was success or failure
- If success, I want to load it into Bigquery - dataset A, table named population_YYYYMMDD. And the csv file will move to another folder - Success Folder (Same or Different Bucket is also ok)
- If failure, the csv file will move to Failure Folder

Comment: are you using a separate task for the conditional block? Could you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: I add a separate task. I want to load a file to bigquery and move that successful csv file to other bucket (Folder A). If failure, it won't load to bigquery, it just move that csv file to bucket named Folder B. In front of me, I just completed to load a file from local to gcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/concepts.html?highlight=branch%20operator#branching) in Airflow for implementing the conditional block in your case. This operator calls a python callable function which in turn returns the `task_id` of the next task to be executed.

Since you've not shared any code, here is a simple exampler dag you can follow. Pls feel free to replace the `DummyOperator` with your requirement specific operators.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance

default_args = {
'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1)
}
def _choose_best_model(**kwargs):
    dag_instance = kwargs['dag']
    execution_date= kwargs['execution_date']
    operator_instance = dag_instance.get_task("Dataflow-operator")
    task_status = TaskInstance(operator_instance, execution_date).current_state()      
    if task_status == 'success':
        return 'upload-to-BQ'
    else:
        return 'upload-to-GCS'

with DAG('branching', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:
    task1 = DummyOperator(task_id='Local-to-GCS')
    task2 = DummyOperator(task_id='Dataflow-operator')
    branching = BranchPythonOperator(
                            task_id='conditional-task',
                            python_callable=_choose_best_model,
                            provide_context=True
                            )
    accurate = DummyOperator(task_id='upload-to-BQ')
    inaccurate = DummyOperator(task_id='upload-to-GCS')
    
task1>>task2
branching >> [accurate, inaccurate]
```

Here `_choose_best_model` function is called by `BranchPythonOperator`, this function determines the state of Task2 (which in your case would be `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator`) and if the task is successful it will return the one task skipping the other.

[image]